# несколько конструкторов копирования

Tags: c++

mainclass.h

```
class Circle
{
protected:
    int x, y;
public:
    Circle()
    {
        cout << "Circle()" << endl;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    Circle(int x, int y)
    {
        
        cout << "Circle(int x, int y)" << endl;
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;

    }
    Circle(const Circle& p)//конструктор копирования
    {
        cout << "Circle(const Circle& p)" << endl;
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;
    }
    Circle(const Circle* p)//принимает указатель на константный объект
    {
        cout << "Circle(сonst Circle* p)" << endl;
        x = p->x;
        y = p->y;
    }
    ~Circle()
    {
        cout << x << "\t" << y << endl;
        cout << "~Circle()" << endl;
    }

    void moveCircle(int dx, int dy)
    {
        cout << "void moveCircle(int dx, int dy)" << endl;
        x = x + dx;
        y = y + dy;
    }
    void reset();

};
void Circle::reset()
{
    cout << "void Circle::reset()" << endl;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}
```

composite.h

```
class doubleCircle
{
protected:
    Circle* p1;
    Circle* p2;
public:
    doubleCircle()
    {
        cout << "doubleCircle()" << endl;
        p1 = new Circle;
        p2 = new Circle;
    }
    doubleCircle(int x1, int y1,int x2,int y2)
    {
        cout << "doubleCircle(int x1, int y1,int x2,int y2)" << endl;
        p1 = new Circle(x1, y1);
        p2 = new Circle(x2, y2);
    }
    doubleCircle(const doubleCircle& s)
    {
        cout << "doubleCircle(const Circle& s)" << endl;
        
        //1)Поверхностное копирование
        /*p1 = s.p1;
        p2 = s.p2;*/
        //ошибка , т.к оно просто копирует адрес указателя, оно не выделяет новую память 
        // и не копирует содержимое, на которое указывает указатель в правой части

        //2) Глубокое копирование
         p1 = new Circle(*s.p1);
        p2 = new Circle(*s.p2);
        //выделяется память для копии и затем копируется фактическое значение 
    
    }
    doubleCircle(const doubleCircle* s)
    {
        cout << "doubleCircle(const doubleCircle* s)" << endl;
        p1 = new Circle(s->p1);
        p2 = new Circle((*s).p2);
    }
    ~doubleCircle()
    {
        cout << "~doubleCircle()" << endl;
        delete p1;
        delete p2;
    }
};
```

У меня есть конструктор копирования для класса композиции ( полями которого являются два указателя на объекты одного другого класса ), в котором реализовано глубокое копирование :

```
doubleCircle(const doubleCircle& s)
    {
        cout << "doubleCircle(const Circle& s)" << endl;
        
        //1)Поверхностное копирование
        /*p1 = s.p1;
        p2 = s.p2;*/
        //ошибка , т.к оно просто копирует адрес указателя, оно не выделяет новую память 
        // и не копирует содержимое, на которое указывает указатель в правой части

        //2) Глубокое копирование
         p1 = new Circle(*s.p1);
        p2 = new Circle(*s.p2);
        //выделяется память для копии и затем копируется фактическое значение 
    
    }
```

Преподователь спросил меня , какой конструктор еще нужно добавить , что бы не прописывать звездочку в скобках , на ум приходит только конструктор , который принимает указатель на объект :

```
doubleCircle(const doubleCircle* s)
    {
        cout << "doubleCircle(const doubleCircle* s)" << endl;
        p1 = new Circle(s->p1);
        p2 = new Circle((*s).p2);
    }
```

Но в нем опять же используется разыменование . Есть ли какие то другие способы сделать такой конструктор  ,или я сделал правильно ?
int main

```
//проверка конструктора копирования , который принимает ссылку
            doubleCircle* s1 = new doubleCircle;
            doubleCircle* s2 = new doubleCircle(*s1);

            //проверка конструктора копирования , который принимает указатель 
            doubleCircle* s3 = new doubleCircle;
            doubleCircle* s4 = new doubleCircle(s3);

            delete s1;
            delete s2;
            delete s3;
            delete s4;
```

Comment: Покажите что это за p1, p2... А по сути дела, нужен конструктор копирования для Circle

Comment: добавил в описание код базового класса , и класс композиции , у которого в полях как раз указатели на объекты базового класса

Comment: а почему бы не убрать указатели в классе "два кольца"? вот здесь `Circle* p1;Circle* p2;` или, если так хочется, заменить их на умные указатели (но это перебор). И сразу все упростится.

Comment: это требуется по заданию

Comment: умные указатели пока не проходили

Comment: ну тогда меняем преподавателя и пишем как нужно:) хотя тут такое дело. класс Circle уже имеет конструктор, который принимает указатель на себя подобного. А значит, вместо `p1 = new Circle(*s.p1);` можно писать `p1 = new Circle(s.p1);`

Comment: этот конструктор я написал позднее , тогда когда препод спросил меня , у меня этого конструктора не было

Comment: ну даже если так  ,я попробовал , пока что ошибка

Comment: ошибка "выражение должно иметь тип класса , но имеет тип const doubleCircle*"

Comment: код в main добавил

Comment: взял код - вроде компилится. убрал звездочки, где я писал - оно все равно компилируется. Не вижу проблемы, кроме жуткого страшного кода.

Comment: конструктор перемещения подойдет если не нужно сохранять объект который копируете.